# How to count the number of a value in each month and year?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I count the number of 'cancel' value in each month and year?

```
 res                   date
---------------------------------------   
cancel                 2022-05-02
cancel                 2022-04-22
cancel                 2022-04-08
cancel                 2022-03-01
```

MS SQL

expected output:

```
 month&year          numcases
-------------------------------
05-2022                  300
04-2022                  543
```

ETC....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can start trying something like this:

```
SELECT YEAR([date]), MONTH([date]), COUNT(*) AS [Number]
FROM [Table]
GROUP BY YEAR([date]), MONTH([date])
```

The column [date] should be datetime. If it's text you will have to cast it:

```
SELECT YEAR(CAST([date] AS datetime)), ...
```

Comment: _The column [date] should be datetime_ Or datetime2 or smalldatetime or ...